# Is Azan allowed to be recited for any social purpose?

Tags: sunnah, adhan

In my village, Azan is recited to help people wake up for Sahri in the time of Ramadan. Is such a practice allowed? Generally speaking, **is it allowed to use Azan PUBLICLY for as a signal?**

Note that I am aware that Azan should (or must? I am not sure) be recited after birth of a child. Therefore, I suspect there may be some other FIXED purposes of Azan.

Comment: in the movie " ar-risala" they showed bilal reciting athan to call the sahaba for an anouncment, but i dont know how accurate the movie is...

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, there are other occasions for which Adhaan can be used. Adhaan was originally legislated to call people to prayer for the five obligatory prayers and the Jumu'ah.

Another permissible occasion is upon seeing a spirit or apparition from the Jinn because of the hadith :

> When the Jinn try to mislead you (by taking different shapes), hasten
>   to pronounce Adhan (call to Prayer). [***Narrated by Jabir ibn 'Abdullah, Musnad Ahmad no. 13865]***

Calling out adhaan when someone sees the Jinn, will drive him away.

This is what is legislated from Sunnah.

**Source:** [Ruling on announcing Adhan for purposes other than Salah](http://alifta.com/Fatawa/Fatwaprint.aspx?id=1180&BookID=8&sectionid=)

Comment: Are these two are only permitted occasion or you can remember just these? It would be nice if you draw a conclusion.

Comment: @Mohayemin It is what is legislated from Sunnah. I have added my source.

Comment: The question is *"Is Azan allowed to be recited for any social purpose?"* which is expected to have a *yes/no* answer. If you add a *yes/no* at the top of the answer, I could accept it.